# Way to change Notebook's indent width?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

By default, the front end auto-indents multi-line expressions somewhat nicely.  However, it can be somewhat difficult to distinguish between indent levels (particularly for longer code) with the default indent width of 2 spaces.  Is there a way to increase the auto-indent width?

Searching around, including diving into the option inspector, didn't yield any results.

Comment: see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIndent.html  you can change it in option inspector.

Comment: @nasser Ok, now I don't know how I missed that in a search.  Thanks!